# scikits.audiolab on Ubuntu Oneiric - ImportError: No module named _sndfile

Tags: python

Okay, so I wanted to do some basic signal processing in Python and found this great library called `scikits.audiolab`.

No PPA anywhere to be found. Oh well. I thought I could install it on my Ubuntu Oneiric server by simply

```
sudo aptitude install libsndfile-dev
```

and then

```
sudo easy_install scikits.audiolab
```

This, however, failed with

```
error: sndfile (http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) library not found.
Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
site.cfg file, in section [sndfile].
```

Wtf? Okay, queried the `libsndfile1-dev` file list:

```
japsu@helios ~ $ apt-file list libsndfile1-dev
libsndfile1-dev: /usr/include/sndfile.h
libsndfile1-dev: /usr/include/sndfile.hh
libsndfile1-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsndfile.a
libsndfile1-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsndfile.la
libsndfile1-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so
libsndfile1-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/sndfile.pc
[...]
```

Weird, libraries going into non-standard library directory? Stupid packager.

Oh well. Downloaded the source for `scikits.audiolab`, wrote a `site.cfg` like this:

```
[sndfile]
include_dirs = /usr/include
library_dirs = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
sndfile_libs = sndfile
```

Now `python setup.py build` and `sudo setup.py install` completed successfully.

Next, fired up a Python shell, tried to `from scikits.audiolab import sndfile`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "scikits/audiolab/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pysndfile import formatinfo, sndfile
  File "scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _sndfile import Sndfile, Format, available_file_formats, \
ImportError: No module named _sndfile
```

But:

```
>> sys.path
['',
 '/usr/bin',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scikits.audiolab-0.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/Extensions',
 u'/home/japsu/.ipython']
```

And `_sndfile.so` found at `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scikits.audiolab-0.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.so`.

So, my question is,

1. Wtf is going on? Why doesn't python find `_sndfile.so`?
2. Has anyone successfully used `scikits.audiolab` in 2011 on a 2011 Linux distro? How did you do it?
3. Are there any good alternative libraries for reading HUGE (like, 10 GB / 8 hours) WAV files chunk by chunk into NumPy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone suggested I check `ldd _sndfile.so`. Did just that and got

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffd3dea000)
    libsndfile.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1 (0x00007f2bfbb5b000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f2bfb93e000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2bfb59e000)
    libFLAC.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8 (0x00007f2bfb354000)
    libvorbisenc.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2 (0x00007f2bfae85000)
    libvorbis.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0 (0x00007f2bfac58000)
    libogg.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0 (0x00007f2bfaa51000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2bfa7cd000)
```

Interesting! A bunch of file format libraries are also referenced, ones that I probably do not have installed.

Did `sudo aptitude install flac vorbis-tools` and voila!

```
In [1]: from scikits.audiolab import sndfile
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scikits.audiolab-0.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_6                                     
4.egg/scikits/audiolab/soundio/play.py:48: UserWarning: Could not import alsa ba                                     
ckend; most probably, you did not have alsa headers when building audiolab
warnings.warn("Could not import alsa backend; most probably, "
```

I can probably ignore that warning about missing ALSA support for now as it's probably used for local recording and playback - and this is a server anyway.

It would have been a whole lot easier if the lack of `libFLAC`, `libvorbis` and `libvorbisenc` had triggered a build-time failure in the build scripts of `scikits.audiolab`... After all, the final error message mentions nothing of those libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I just realized this is not the case as pysndfile seems to be bundled... I shouldn't be answering stuff the first thing in the morning ;)

Answer to 1: Sndfile is a c library, you most probably need to install the python wrapper for it: http://code.google.com/p/libsndfile-python/

Answer (score 0):

I you don't want to have the warning about alsa headers, just install the lib.

sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev

That worked for me..