# scikits audiolab installation error

Tags: python, linux, alsa, scikits

I am using mint Linux Mint 13 maya (linux  3.2.0-23-generic x86-64)
I am trying to install scikits.audiolab for performing some audio signal processing. I have downloaded all prerequisites i.e. (python-dev python-numpy python-setuptools libsndfile-dev). 
I have made site.cfg as

```
[sndfile]
include_dirs = /usr/include/
library_dirs = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

I get following error

```
SndfileInfo:
    FOUND:
libraries = ['sndfile']
library_dirs = ['/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/']
include_dirs = ['/usr/include/']

    AlsaInfo:
libraries asound not found in /usr/local/lib
libraries asound not found in /usr/lib
scikits/audiolab/soundio/setup.py:21: UserWarning: Alsa not found - alsa backend not build
warnings.warn("Alsa not found - alsa backend not build")
CoreAudioInfo:
scikits/audiolab/soundio/setup.py:31: UserWarning: CoreAudio not found - CoreAudio backend not build
warnings.warn("CoreAudio not found - CoreAudio backend not build")
```

when I do '$locate asound' i get

```
/usr/include/alsa/asoundef.h
/usr/include/alsa/asoundlib.h
/usr/include/alsa/sound/asound_fm.h
/usr/include/linux/ultrasound.h
/usr/include/sound/asound.h
/usr/include/sound/asound_fm.h
/usr/include/sys/asoundlib.h
/usr/include/sys/ultrasound.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/ultrasound.h
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_conf_pulse.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_ctl_arcam_av.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_ctl_bluetooth.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_ctl_oss.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_ctl_pulse.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_bluetooth.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_jack.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_oss.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_pulse.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_speex.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_upmix.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_usb_stream.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_vdownmix.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_samplerate.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_samplerate_best.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_samplerate_linear.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_samplerate_medium.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_samplerate_order.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_speexrate.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_speexrate_best.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_speexrate_medium.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_conf_pulse.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_ctl_arcam_av.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_ctl_bluetooth.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_ctl_oss.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_ctl_pulse.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_bluetooth.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_jack.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_oss.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_pulse.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_speex.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_upmix.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_usb_stream.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_vdownmix.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_samplerate.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_samplerate_best.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_samplerate_linear.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_samplerate_medium.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_samplerate_order.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_speexrate.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_speexrate_best.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_speexrate_medium.so
/usr/share/doc/libasound2
/usr/share/doc/libasound2-dev
/usr/share/doc/libasound2-plugins
/usr/share/doc/libasound2/NEWS.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libasound2/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libasound2/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libasound2/examples
/usr/share/doc/libasound2/examples/asoundrc.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/libasound2-plugins/README-arcam-av
/usr/share/doc/libasound2-plugins/README-jack
/usr/share/doc/libasound2-plugins/README-maemo.gz
/usr/share/doc/libasound2-plugins/README-pcm-oss
/usr/share/doc/libasound2-plugins/README-pulse
/usr/share/doc/libasound2-plugins/a52.txt
/usr/share/doc/libasound2-plugins/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libasound2-plugins/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libasound2-plugins/examples
/usr/share/doc/libasound2-plugins/lavcrate.txt
/usr/share/doc/libasound2-plugins/samplerate.txt
/usr/share/doc/libasound2-plugins/speexdsp.txt
/usr/share/doc/libasound2-plugins/speexrate.txt
/usr/share/doc/libasound2-plugins/upmix.txt
/usr/share/doc/libasound2-plugins/vdownmix.txt
/usr/share/doc/libasound2-plugins/examples/a52.conf_pulse
/usr/share/doc/libasound2-plugins/examples/asound.conf_jack
/usr/share/doc/libasound2-plugins/examples/asound.conf_oss
/usr/share/local-repository/binary/lib32asound2_1.0.25-1ubuntu10_amd64.deb
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-23/include/linux/ultrasound.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-23/include/sound/asound.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-23/include/sound/asound_fm.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-23/include/sound/asoundef.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-23/sound/oss/dmasound
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-23/sound/oss/dmasound/Kconfig
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-23/sound/oss/dmasound/Makefile
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-23-generic/include/linux/ultrasound.h
/var/cache/apt/archives/libasound2-dev_1.0.25-1ubuntu10.1_amd64.deb
/var/lib/alsa/asound.state
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libasound2-dev.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libasound2-dev.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libasound2-dev.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libasound2-plugins:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libasound2-plugins:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libasound2-plugins:i386.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libasound2-plugins:i386.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libasound2:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libasound2:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libasound2:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libasound2:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libasound2:amd64.preinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libasound2:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libasound2:amd64.symbols
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libasound2:i386.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libasound2:i386.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libasound2:i386.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libasound2:i386.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libasound2:i386.preinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libasound2:i386.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libasound2:i386.symbols
```

How do I make the setup.py find the libraries. Is there something I am missing ?
I have seen http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=3748397 and [scikits.audiolab on Ubuntu Oneiric - ImportError: No module named _sndfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461055/scikits-audiolab-on-ubuntu-oneiric-importerror-no-module-named-sndfile)

This is causing so much frustation

UPDATE

In one of my PC's this error was removed on completely un-installing the scikits-audiolab and alsa and then updating the apt-get before re-installing alsa and scikits-audiolab.

Answer (score 3):

The following made the alsa audio backend work for me on Ubuntu.

As directed in http://cournape.github.io/audiolab/installing.html#installation-from-sources, install alsa headers:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev
```

In the source directory either,

/path-to/scikits.audiolab-0.11.0/

or, if using pip (source is downloaded by default to /tmp)

/tmp/pip-build/scikits.audiolab

create a site.cfg file, and in addition to the [sndfile] section create an [alsa] section:

```
[sndfile]
include_dirs = /usr/include
library_dirs = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
[alsa]
include_dirs = /usr/include/alsa
library_dirs = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Use locate or apt-file list to find where asoundlib.h (include_dirs) and libasound.so (library_dirs) are located in your system.

Well, after doing all this and trying to reinstall, it still didn't work. I kept getting the same frustrating message:

```
SndfileInfo:
  FOUND:
    libraries = ['sndfile']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
    include_dirs = ['/usr/include']

AlsaInfo:
  alsa not found
scikits/audiolab/soundio/setup.py:21: UserWarning: Alsa not found - alsa backend not build
  warnings.warn("Alsa not found - alsa backend not build")
```

So, I had to use this hack. Open the file /path-to/scikits.audiolab-0.11.0/scikits/audiolab/soundio/setup.py and replace

```
14 alsa_info = info_factory('alsa', ['asound'], ['alsa/asoundlib.h'],
15                          classname='AlsaInfo')()
```

with

```
alsa_info = info_factory('alsa', ['asound'], ['asoundlib.h'],
                         classname='AlsaInfo')()
```

If this works for more people, we can ask [David Cournapeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11465/david-cournapeau) (scikits.audiolab author) to make this patch.

Comment: Hi @ravich2_7183, its interesting that you found a solution to this problem. I will check-out this patch/heck as I get some time, right now am occupied with stuff. In past, I had *reinstalled* a lot of stuff to make audiolabs work on my linuxMint13. I wish, I had found such a patch then.